# Get SVG image from assets and set it to custom listview adapter Android

Tags: android

I am working on a project where I have to set the svg image in listview adapter. Listview adapter is custom and I already get all the images from assets folder in a list but dont know how to set these svg images in listview adapter or to set in the imageview .. Can anyone help please please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

For using svg images, you will have to convert these images in Vector Images.

Procedure for using svg is:
right click  on
1. res directory  -> New  ->  Vector Asset (will found in API 21 for supporting svg images)  -> Here you will have option for choosing default material icons from **Material Icon** or you choose from your system from **Local Svg Images**
2. Local svg images -> image file
Here from image file you can choose your system images which you desires.

Then these images you can set anywhere just be setting background attribute.

timericon.xml

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="27dp"
    android:height="27dp"
    android:viewportWidth="27.0"
    android:viewportHeight="27.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M13.5,26.6c-7.2,0 -13.1,-5.9 -13.1,-13.1c0,-7.2 5.9,-13.1 13.1,-13.1c7.2,0 13.1,5.9 13.1,13.1C26.6,20.8 20.7,26.6 13.5,26.6zM13.5,3.8c-5.4,0 -9.7,4.4 -9.7,9.7c0,5.4 4.4,9.7 9.7,9.7c5.4,0 9.7,-4.4 9.7,-9.7C23.2,8.1 18.9,3.8 13.5,3.8zM20.4,14.6h-7.4c-0.3,0 -0.5,-0.3 -0.6,-0.6c0,0 0,0 0,0v0v-5.7v-0.1c0,-0.6 0.5,-1.1 1.1,-1.1c0.6,0 1.1,0.5 1.1,1.1v0.6v2.9v0c0,0 0,0 0,0c0,0 0,0 0,0v0c0,0.3 0.3,0.5 0.5,0.6l5.2,0c0.6,0 1,0.5 1,1.1C21.4,14.1 20.9,14.5 20.4,14.6z"
    android:fillColor="#F44336"/>
```

main_layout.xml

```
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="21dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/timericon"
                    android:id="@+id/timerl"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fifteen"
                    />
```

**Hope this might helpful to you !**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But i want to use svg format direct instead to convert in vector format. Do you have any idea to set svg format ?

Comment: as per my understanding, we can't use it directly as in android studio , on creating navigation drawer activity, it also provide vector images directly instead of svg images, but you can use ttf images directly.

Comment: can you add a code snippet to use vector images if i convert svg format to vector as you say?

Comment: code snippet being added , let me know whether its working or not

Comment: yes it might worked. But i have to use this vector image in custom listview adapter ? Any idea about this?

Comment: could you let me know where in listview adapter you have to use,  in its item  layout or somewhere else

Comment: while using custom adapter we inflate xml layout with one row only and use the BaseAdapter for that and i am getting the different images from JSON and set these images to arraylist of BaseAdapter

Comment: in json response which type of images you are getting, are you getting image url or from res directory. If getting from res dir, directly set images using setBackgroundDrawable method, pl let me know which type of images in json you are getting

Comment: we are getting svg image from JSON and these images are in subfolder of our assets folder  like assets/www/images

Comment: (http://www.kiodev.com/svg-rendering-on-android/) , hope this url might help you or just put all you asset images in drawable folder by converting them into vector images and make their json response from res drawable for image rendering

Comment: yes i checked this and tried also it works only for one image as i pass id to it like R.raw.id_of_image but not working for multiple images.

Comment: then just do it by putting your image in drawable and make its json response

Comment: svg is not supported by drawable folder so i keep it in raw folder. I stuck in it and unable to show the image Please do something..

Comment: svg is not supported but vector is supported that you can convert from svg from steps I already told how to convert svg to vector